# A `find` that returns the condition value, not the element value

Tags: ruby, enumerator

I am scanning for an element in `source` that satisfies a condition. The condition is often, but not always, a regexp match. I'm looking for a version of `find` that returns the result of the condition, not the original element. With `find`, I have to re-compute the criterion for the successful element.

The best I worked out runs along this line:

```
source.find {|e| if (m = e.match(/(e.)/)); break m[0]; end}
```

To avoid semicolons prompting Rubocop to complain about multi-statement lines, I prefer to write as follows:

```
source.find {|e| break m[0] if (m = e.match(/(e.)/))}
```

But Ruby can't cope with the forward reference (and I'm not twisted enough to re-use `e` for `m`).

Is there something more elegant to do this job with the short-cutting?

Comment: In case you didn't know, you can upvote answers as well as select the one you find most helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have `break`, you don't need `find` to break. Use `each`.

```
source.each {|e| m = e[/e./] and break m}
```

Comment: Too engrossed with 'find' and 'inject' cleverness. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Though I prefer what @sawa suggests, you could use an instance variable:

```
["dog", "cat", "emu", "pig"].find { |e| $da_match = e[/(e.)/] }
  #=> "emu"
$da_match 
  #=> "em"
```

or, for your regex:

```
["dog", "cat", "emu", "pig"].find { |e| e =~ /(e.)/ }
  #=> "emu" 
$1
  #=> "em"
```

If the regular expression `r` does not (or may not) have an outer capture group, you could add one like so: `/(#{r})/`. For example,

```
r0 = /e./
r1 = /(#{r0})/
  #/((?-mix:e.))/

["dog", "cat", "emu", "pig"].find { |e| e =~ r1 }
  #=> "emu" 
$1 
  #=> "em"
```

Depending on how the regex is used, this may not work. If the (original) regex contains one or more capture groups, what was capture group 1 would become capture group 2, and so on. Therefore, if the content of one of those capture groups is referenced within the regex or in subsequent code, an incorrect value would be obtained. This would not be a problem, however, if you used named capture groups and reserved a name for outer one being added:

```
["dog", "cat", "emu", "pig"].find { |e| e =~ /(?<outer>#{/e./})/ }
  #=> "emu" 
$~[:outer]
  #=> "em"
```

`$~` is a global variable containing the most recent `MatchData` object.